# Google Chrome Not Honoring Mac Keychain Settings

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, certificate, self-signed

I have a self-signed certificate that I generated as a `.p12` and imported into Mac Keychain. I've set the trust to `Always Trust` however Google Chrome still shows `Not Secure` and prompts me with `Your connection is not private`. Safari is trusting the certificate just fine. Does anyone know how to fix this? See image below (Its not incognito, its just a dark theme)

[image]

Comment: Same problem. Any feedback ?

Comment: Same problem also.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, but I cannot reproduce to confirm.

1) Open Chrome

2) Go to chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost

3) Enabled it. Then relaunch.

4) Then disable it again. Then relaunch.

I use this for a local domain which is formatted https://xxx.xxx.com.local i.e. it wasn't just for https://localhost

Answer (score 0):

you should add a x509 SAN extension to the cert.

[image]